# Knex Support for Read Replicas

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

Does Knex support routing queries to MySQL read replicas like [Sequelize does](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/docs/usage/#read-replication)? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported currently in knex (0.14).

To accomplish something similar you need to create multiple `knex` instances and explicitly send read queries to read replica `knex` instances and write queries to master instance.

There has been discussion about implementing this feature, but I don't think that anyone is currently working on it.

Comment: Just started using Knex and was hoping to see this as a feature (supported_ for MSSSQL,   This would be part of a traditional connection string which could be used to speak with the ReadOnly replica in the high availability group :   ApplicationIntent: 'readOnly .  My Current version of SQL is 2017.  Any help would be appreciated.  Does Knex support raw connection strings?

Comment: If DB driver supports the feature, it might be possible to use with knex also.